# Датировка заимствований

Tags: лексика, история, заимствования

Мне задали вопрос, на который не представляю где искать ответ. Возможно ли определить, хотя бы с точностью до 20-30 лет, когда слово "неофит" начали писать по-русски? Кто может подсказать, где порыться?

Answer (score 2):

Из [Нацкорпуса](http://search-beta.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&spd=&text=lexgramm&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=%ED%E5%EE%F4%E8%F2&gramm1=&sem1=&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&flags1=&m1=&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=1&lex2=&gramm2=&sem2=&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2&flags2=&m2=&p=18):

> Иоаким, еп. новгородский. **Неофит**, еп. черниговский. Феодор, еп.
>   ростовский.
>   *[В.Н.Татищев. История российская в семи томах. Том второй (**1750**)]*
>
> Ведьма и демон занимали место кумы и кума, отрекаясь за **неофита**
>   Антонио от Бога, добра и спасения...
>    *[Е. А. Баратынский. Перстень (**1832**)]*

Answer (score 1):

Ройтесь в [Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%82&year_start=1700&year_end=1900&corpus=25&smoothing=1&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%82%3B%2Cc0)! Он говорит, что в 1851 "неофит" уже писали по-русски.

Comment: Спасибо, интересный сервис. Если б они ещё источник указывали...

Comment: Нашла еще [Advanced Book Search](https://books.google.com.au/advanced_book_search?hl=en).  Выбираем Русский в языках, заполняем слово и годы издания, например, 1700-1855. Он выдает кучу книг,  и я не уверена, что русских!